# как вычислять синус и косинус в python, не используя math

Tags: python, формулы

Доброго времени суток!
Дело вот в чём:

Есть потребность точно вычислять синус и косинус, с возможность изменения точности(как decimal.getcontext().prec=...).

Math, понятное дело, такой возможности не даёт.

Я, если честно, вообще не понимаю, в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: Добавляйте случайные числа к результату `math.sin`.

Comment: Вы это серьёзно?

Comment: и правда, сейчас заметил, что мой комментарий похож на шутку. Но, все же, я думаю, что сопроцессор посчитает синус с максимально доступной точностью быстрее, чем алгоритм с заданной точностью на Python. Если вы дополните вопрос и напишете, с какой целью и в каком контексте нужно управлять точностью, то, может, что-то более конкретно можно будет ответить.

Comment: Да так.. Решил немного продвинуться в изучении вычислений. Практикуюсь с созданием калькулятора. Я относительно новичок пока-что

Comment: Если задача учебная, то, возможно, синус нужно посчитать через ряд Тейлора, вот вам и направление, в какую сторону двигаться.

Comment: цепные дроби в помощь, но они сходятся быстро - http://algorithm.narod.ru/el/sicota.html

Comment: или - все функции 30 лет назад я брал здесь:
http://nashol.com/2012041064410/spravochnik-po-specialnim-funkciyam-s-formulami-grafikami-i-matimaticheskimi-tablicami-abramovic-m-stigan-i-1979.html
Вряд ли для синуса есть что то лучше )

Comment: Не забудьте в расчетах, что считают синусы от 0 до 90 градусов, большие углы и косинусы по формулам приведения.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Sin, cos etc for Python 2 Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10951795/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация по decimal модулю](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-recipes) содержит примеры вычисления sin, cos:

```
def sin(x):
    """Return the sine of x as measured in radians.

    The Taylor series approximation works best for a small value of x.
    For larger values, first compute x = x % (2 * pi).

    >>> print(sin(Decimal('0.5')))
    0.4794255386042030002732879352
    >>> print(sin(0.5))
    0.479425538604
    >>> print(sin(0.5+0j))
    (0.479425538604+0j)

    """
    getcontext().prec += 2
    i, lasts, s, fact, num, sign = 1, 0, x, 1, x, 1
    while s != lasts:
        lasts = s
        i += 2
        fact *= i * (i-1)
        num *= x * x
        sign *= -1
        s += num / fact * sign
    getcontext().prec -= 2
    return +s
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое лучшее, что нашёл- ряд Тейлора.

Вот функция, если интересно:

```
def q(x):
    Decimal(x)
def sin(x):
    tmp=getcontext().prec
    getcontext().prec=tmp+50
    x=q(x)
    n=x
    r = 0;
    i = 1;
    while ((-n,n)[n>0] > q("1E-"+str(getcontext().prec))):
        r += n;
        n *= q(-1) * x * x / ((2 * i) * (2 * i + 1));
        i+=1
    getcontext().prec=tmp
    return q(r)
```